# JavaScript - how to set caret position in pixel?

Tags: javascript, angular, position, pixel, caret

Exist way how to set caret pixel position in editable DIV with JavaScript (Angular, jQuery)? I look for this functionality many days.

Get caret position in pixel I can do with [this](https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper) (there is problem with autowrapped long text).

I need switch from one editable DIV to another with UP/DOWN key handler and I need same position of caret. Fe. if I have DIV#2 and caret position is after third X (30px from left), then click UP key. I need switch caret to DIV#1 on last line (computed with autowrap text) on same position from left (30px from left! not after third I). As on this animation:

[image: showcase]

Please, help me!

Comment: TinyMCE works with pixel positions. But I need same in editable DIVs.